# Jquery program will not work in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome

I am fairly new to Jquery, considering I just started learning it today. However, I am having a problem with getting my jquery program to work:

Here is the CSS:

```
p {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Here is the Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p").delay(1000).fadeTo("fast", 100);
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PP1114</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="PP1114.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="PP1114.css">
            <!-- these are both links to documents on my computer-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Done!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Very simple program. I wanted for the p element to fade in a second after the page opened, but I always end up with a blank page. In Google Chromes inspect element tool, I looked to see if the html file was retrieving the css and jquery files correctly, which it was. I know my css file is working, so therefore I think the problem may have something to do with Chrome reading the Jquery program. I did lots of troubleshooting, but couldn't seem to fix it. What's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't included `jquery.js` in on your page. Add the following just *before* the other `<script>` inside the `<head>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.js"></script>
```

Or include the version at Google's CDN:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or include a version stored on your own web server.

Then your JS will work fine, although the second parameter to `fadeTo()` should be `1` rather than `100`: (`opacity` isn't a percentage).

Note that if you had looked for errors in your browser's console (which in Chrome you can open with F12 or ctrl-shift-I) you would've seen this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

...which is a pretty strong hint that jQuery isn't available.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/isutim/1/edit

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much, and I will be sure to keep the rest of that information for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

Have you included jquery-1.9.1.js file?You can also include it from jquery.org.From your code I guess that may be causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

Javascript's built-in setTimeout() should work in Chrome.

```
window.setTimeout(function () { $("p").fadeTo("fast", 100); }, 1000);
```

Comment: `setTimeout()` will work, but so will the OP's original code.